# Jawr: Is making on bundle wait until another bundle is finished possible?

Tags: javascript, java, webpack, jawr

So I hope I can the describe my problem properly. So i have the following in my `jawr.properties`:

```
jawr.js.bundle.proj-react.id=/bundles/proj-react.js
jawr.js.bundle.proj-react.mappings=npm:/proj/js/package.json(dist/p.webpack.js)
jawr.js.bundle.proj-react.bundlepostprocessors=none
```

and after that I have

```
jawr.js.bundle.other-js.id=/bundles/other-js.js
jawr.js.bundle.other-js.mappings=/proj/js/node_modules/@other/dist/utils/i18n.js
```

My problem is that the first part runs npm install som it's not certain that the node_modules files exist until `jawr.js.bundle.proj-react.mappings` has finished.

Is it possible to "delay" `other-js` somehow until `proj-react` is finished?